# Evitar Duplicidad en envio de datos AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

La verdad, mis conocimientos en JS y Ajax no son muy grandes y por ello recurro a ustedes.
Mi problema radica en un script o funcion que envia una variable para la impresion POS.
Trabajo actualmente con Datatables, Ajax, PHP y Mysql.

En mi datatables, tengo lo siguiente:

```
{
"sClass": "alignRight",
'data' : null,
'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
  var idv = row['id'];
  var comanda = row['comanda'];
  var comanda_bar = row['comanda_bar'];
  var estado = row['estado'];

  if (comanda === 'S' && estado === 'S' && comanda_bar === 'N'){
     return '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded btn-warning acciones" onClick="individual();" id="' + idv + '">IMPRIME</span>';
  }else if (comanda === 'N' && estado === 'S' && comanda_bar === 'S'){
     return '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded btn-warning acciones" onClick="individual();" id="' + idv + '">IMPRIME</span>';
  }
  }
  }
```

Lo que hago basicamente ahi es ver hacia donde imprime dependiendo de las condicionales (si imprime ticket al bar o a la cocina).

La funcion que envia los datos es la siguiente:

```
function individual(){
 $(".acciones").attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
 $(document).on('click', '.acciones', function(e) {

 var idv = this.id;

 $.ajax({
  data: {"dato" : idv},
  url: 'individual.php',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function (response) {
  }
});
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
 });
}
```

Hasta ahi, todo bien. Imprime correctamente los tickets hacia el bar o cocina.
El problema es que cuando imprimo mas de una vez, salen 2 impresiones, es como si quedara un contador que va incrementandose cada vez que se presiona el boton de impresion.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede ser o como puede arreglarse o bien me orienten a como hacerlo?
Agradezco como siempre, la ayuda que me pudisien entregar.
Saludos.

Comment: A que te refieres con imprimir mas de una vez? Es como si se dieran varios clicks al boton imprimir?

Comment: Como dice @Canabix, se entiende que la persona hace varias veces click como si intentará apurar el proceso. No podrías entonces apenas la persona haga click bloquear el botón hasta que no obtengas una respuesta en el successs?

Comment: @Canabix gracias por responder. Lo que pasa es que ese boton esta ahi porque no es la idea imprimir cada vez al ticket completo de pedidos que un cliente hace. Ya que al comprar algo, se agrega al listado de productos de la venta, entonces, como el tema esta referido a Bar, el boton lo que hace es imprimir el producto o comanda de forma individual (el producto por si solo) y no todos los pedidos ya enviados anteriormente. Mi pregunta pasa porque cada vez que imprimo un ticket individual, este se imprime mas de una vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente en tu función individual, para evitar que la función se ejecute mas de una vez.

Agregas una bandera **procesando** y mientras no se haya terminado de ejecutar el ajax solo le indicamos salir de la funcion.

```
 procesando = false;

 function individual()
 {
      $(".acciones").attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
      $(document).on('click', '.acciones', function(e){

        if(procesando==true)
        return;

        procesando = true;

             var idv = this.id;

             $.ajax({
              data: {"dato" : idv},
              url: 'individual.php',
              type: 'POST',
              success: function (response) {
                  procesando = false;
              }
          });
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
       });
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias estimado. hice las pruebas y funciono como necesitaba. Ahora solo imprime un ticket por cada click que hago. Saludos y gracias nuevamente.